# Buscar texto hasta determinado símbolo

Tags: perl

Un saludo.

Tengo este código con el que busco hasta el final de la línea pero me gustaría que buscara hasta que se encuentre un punto, para que me extraiga un texto con coherencia.

A continuación el código:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $body;
my $smtpCode;


    $body = "Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does
    not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email
    address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser s35si4587705qvc.145 - gsmtp";

    foreach ( split( /\n/, $body ) ) {
        next if (/^\s*$/);

        if ( $_ =~  /^Diagnostic-Code:\ssmtp;\s(.*)$/) {
            $smtpCode = $1;
            print $smtpCode; #Salida: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does

            }
        }
```

Y lo que realmente me gustaría que mostrara es lo siguiente:

```
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does
not exist.
```

O que por lo menos muestre todo el párrafo después de `Diagnostic-Code: smtp;`

```
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does
not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email
address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser s35si4587705qvc.145 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un split buscando por punto, pero entonces se te presenta el problema de que tienes otros puntos en el texto que probablemente no quieras separar (cómo en `550-5.1.1`)

Así que necesitarás algún tipo de *heurística* para dividir por el punto en determinadas circunstancias. Por ejemplo, una posible idea sería dividir por punto cuando éste esté precedido de 0 o más espacios y luego una letra mayúscula. De esta manera dividiríamos cuando lo que hay a continuación **parece** el final de una frase (es sólo una idea, tendrás que determinar tú mismo la manera más adecuada).

Con la idea propuesta, cambiaríamos el split:

`split( m/\.(?=\s*[A-Z])/, $body )`

y opcionalmente podemos borrar los saltos de línea:

`s/\s+/ /g; # Opcional, para quitar los saltos de línea`

Finalmente quedaría así:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $body;
my $smtpCode;


    $body = "Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does
    not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email
    address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser s35si4587705qvc.145 - gsmtp";

    foreach ( split( m/\.(?=\s*[A-Z])/, $body ) ) { # Dividimos por punto siempre que le preceda 0 o más espacios y luego letra mayúscula
        next if (/^\s*$/);

        s/\s+/ /g; # Opcional, para quitar los saltos de línea

        if ( $_ =~  /^Diagnostic-Code:\ssmtp;\s(.*)$/) {
            $smtpCode = $1;
            print $smtpCode;

        }
    }
```

Dicho esto, hay maneras más eficientes (o al menos más cortas de lograr lo mismo).

Suponiendo que solo quieras buscar una vez dentro de `$body`, este código sería equivalente:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $body;
my $smtpCode;


    $body = "Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does
    not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email
    address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser s35si4587705qvc.145 - gsmtp";


    $body =~ s/\s+/ /g; # Opcional, para quitar los saltos de línea
    print $smtpCode = $1 if $body =~ m/Diagnostic-Code:\ssmtp;\s(.*?)(?:$|\.\s*[A-Z])/s;
```

Si necesitases buscar más de una vez, podrías usar un while:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $body;
my $smtpCode;


    $body = "Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does
    not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email
    address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser s35si4587705qvc.145 - gsmtp";


    $body =~ s/\s+/ /g; # Opcional, para quitar los saltos de línea
    while ($body =~ m/Diagnostic-Code:\ssmtp;\s(.*?)(?:$|\.\s*[A-Z])/sg) {
        print $1;
        # ...
        $smtpCode = $1;
        # ...
    }
```